# jQuery UI autocomplete via ajax error:

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've been searching for days now, but can't find a fix.

Here's my code (shortened to the core functionality):

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/ajax.php',
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              'task' : 'tasktodo',
              'squery' : request.term
            }, 
            success: 
                function( data ) {
                    response($.map( data, function(item){
                        return {
                            label : item['name'],
                            value : item['name']
                        }
                    }));
                }
        });     
    }
});
```

The autocomplete does work, but I'm getting the following error in my browser's console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'results' (in Chrome)
 TypeError: this.options.messages.results is not a function (in Firefox)
```

The error points to a line in jqueryui.js, which is called by `"response()"` in my script.

Even though the error doesn't affect the functionality I'd like to know why it's there.

Comment: Could it be that data is null? In this case map fails

Comment: can you share the relevant html also

Comment: it looks like you are enabling an experimental API called `live region extension, adding a `messages` option` somehow... not able to recreate from my end...

Comment: Oh wow, it was really that simple.. deleting the "messages" option solved it. Thanks Arun!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very old question, but still relevant today as it happened me and I'm not sure the accepted answer covers all bases, or explains the problem.

This happens because the autocomplete plugin expects you to provide a messages object with noResults and results properties for telling it how to label search results.

The noResults property should be a string that is displayed when, you've guessed it, there are no results.

The results property then should be a method that accepts a count parameter, and returns a string.

Something like this:

```
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ){
        ... your $.ajax request stuff
    },
    messages: {
        noResults: "No results",
        results: function(count){
            return count + (count == 0 ? ' result' : ' results');
        }
    }
});
```

It's possible that calling `response(data);` avoids the need to set these properties at all. But in my case, a colleague had provided a messages object, but had set both noResults and results properties to string values, hence the error:

> this.options.messages.results is not a function

Comment: Thanks, Breeno, I have marked your answer as the accepted one, as it explains the problem in detail. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
success: function(data){
   response(data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in response data map function , you might have to map like

```
response($.map( data.d, function(item){
return {
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.name
                                }
```

Comment: Tried that and found that it works both ways. Didn't solve the error though, but thanks anyways!